# Styling Taxonomy Terms Individually

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, css

I am trying to solve a problem and need help :) First, I have a custom grid displaying terms and images from my custom taxonomy. This is the code I'm using currently:

```
<?php

$terms = get_terms( 'industrygroups' , 'hide_empty=false' );

echo '<div class="row">';

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

    // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
    echo '<div class="col-lg-3"><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></div>';
}

echo '</div>';

?>
```

What I would like to accomplish now is to use a custom field from my taxonomy term (which has been added via [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). The field is a dropdown, displaying different Levels 1-5.

I want each chosen level to output a different color border/background around the tax term shown in the grid - In the Front End

Now, I have been trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-each-wordpress-post-differently/) which addresses how to accomplish this with posts, however I'm struggling to transfer this train of thought to apply to taxonomy terms. I would love some advice. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this plugin will help you: https://wordpress.org/plugins/mark-posts/

Comment: Sven, while that is pretty cool, it's not quite what I need. I updated my post to specify this style change was needed to display in the front end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the slug of each term as class name (and do the styling via CSS)

```
<?php

echo '<div class="col-lg-3 ' . $term->slug . '">'; // $term->slug is the class name
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
echo '</div>';

?>
```

If you want to use dynamic terms and colors I recommend the [Mark Posts Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mark-posts/); it is possible to manage the terms/colors in the admin area and you can also display the terms/colors in the front end as you can see [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wonderful-141?replies=2#post-5802660):

```
<?php

/*
 * Display terms & colors of a post
 */

$post_markers = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'marker' );

echo '<ul>';

foreach ( $post_markers as $post_marker ) :
  echo '<li>';
  echo __('Marker', 'textdomain') . ': ' . $post_marker->name  . '<br />';
  echo __('Color', 'textdomain') . ': ' . $post_marker->description . '<br />';
  echo '</li>';
endforeach;

echo '</ul>';

?>
```

Comment: Thank you Sven, I will play with those ideas and get back to you. :)

Comment: @streetfire Feel free to let me know if you need further help with this :)

Comment: Is there a way to use this with custom tax terms in the back end? (i.e. set color for parent terms, another for child terms etc)

Comment: @streetfire So you want to assign terms to terms? You can combine multiple terms via [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) within your custom query...

Comment: Please keep in mind to ask a [new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and link to similar questions if you're facing another problem than above :)